# Pausing Python subprocesses from keyboard input without killing the subprocess

Tags: python, signals, subprocess, keyboardinterrupt

I'm working on a project to produce a shell in Python, and one important feature is the ability to pause and background a running subprocess. However the only methods I've found of pausing the subprocess appear to kill it instantly, so I can't resume it later.
Our group has tried excepting KeyboardInterrupt:

```
try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(processName)
    process.communicate()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "control character pressed"
```

and also using signals:

```
def signal_handler(signal,frame):
    print 'control character pressed'

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
process.communicate()
```

Another issue is that both of these only work when Ctrl-C is pressed, nothing else has any effect (I imagine this is why the subprocesses are being killed).

Comment: what do you mean by "pause". Is it "suspend" as with `SIGSTOP/SIGCONT` signals (see [Jobs and sessions](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/))?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have the process dying is because you are allowing the Ctrl+C to reach the subprocess. If you were to use the parameter `preexec_fn = os.setpgrp`, as part of the `Popen` call, then the the child is set to be in a different process group from the parent.

Ctrl+C sends a SIGINT to the complete process group, but since the child is in a different process group, it doesn't receive the SIGINT and thus doesn't die.

After that, the `send_signal()` function can be used to send a SIGSTOP to the child process whenever you want to pause it, and a SIGCONT to resume it.